# How to access static file from a template tag in Django to read a text file?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am building a system where I want to read a text file from my template. This text file is stored in my static folder. In my **app_filters**, I have the following function:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def print_file_content(file_name):
    try:
        file = open(file_name, 'r')
        return file.read()
    except IOError:
        return ''
```

On my template, I am doing this:

```
{% load static %}
{% load app_filters %}

<div>{{ "{% static 'my_file.txt' %}" | print_file_content }}</div>
```

I have the file in my static folder: `myapp/static/my_file.txt`, but the file is not read correctly. And the section just remains empty. How can I fix this issue? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this by doing, just read a file and save it in a variable then, link that variable in dictionary and return with Httpresponse or render.

```
def read_file(request):
    f = open('path/my_file.txt', 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    context = {'file_content': file_content}
    return render(request, "index.html", context) or return HttpResponse(file_content, 
    content_type="text/plain")
```

If you want to pass the content of the text file to your template.html add it to the context variable and access it in your template with {{ file_content }}.